# Simulink sim of rician channel ber process

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm learning simulink and I want to use the rician channle block from the communications blockset. I'm told I need to change the format format. Would anyone have some sample code where they used the rician channels in simulink to model a bit error rate process?

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks appears to have a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ug/a1058282528b1.html) on the subject.  Have you taken a look at that?